# Adding Queue Members

Tags: public-group, queue

What is the best possible way of adding users to **Queues** and **Groups** given that there are a number of Queues and Groups and a number of users belonging to them?

Comment: This is an ambiguous question. I would edit it to make the scenario more concrete.

Comment: Are you happy to use Apex code to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Where possible, add roles or public groups to queues, not individuals. That way it's easier to see what patterns of access are allowed.  It's also much more efficient to add a person to one group than to add a person to many queues.  If your access scheme is well-designed, your groups will have multiple members and will find use in multiple queues.